# Enable ipv6 in XP Mode on Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, routing, ipv6, windows-xp-mode

Upgraded router to ipv6 capable router, ipv6 tunnel and enabled all home network to ipv6. Everything works perfectly except ipv6 in XP Mode. XP Mode is using Win7 host's wifi adapter directly.

After "ipv6 install" i can't even ping localhost. After adding route for localhost and for Win7 host (on LAN2) i can ping6 both, but that's how far it goes. How to get packets routed onwards? Tried to add routing rule with router's ipv6 address but it's unreachable. "ipv6 nc" doesn't show a single ipv6 address from the home network.

I need XP Mode for testing a lot of Windows stuff (now incl ipv6 things) and it's included with the Win7 license, so changing to something else is not really an option.

UPDATE: Made a fresh XP Mode vm for testing. Nothing has been changed from defaults except ipv6 installed. This is how it looks:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig/all
```

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : IPV6-1
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : net.local
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : net.local
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Generic) #2
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-03-FF-E1-6C-89
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.252
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::203:ffff:fee1:6c89%5
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.254
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.254
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.254
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
    Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.254
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, November 19, 2013 6:37:31 PM
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, November 20, 2013 6:37:31 PM
```

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route print

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 03 ff e6 6c 89 ...... Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Generic) - Packet Scheduler Miniport
0x3 ...00 03 ff e1 6c 89 ...... Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Generic) #2 - Packet Scheduler Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.123.254  192.168.123.252      20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
    192.168.123.0    255.255.255.0  192.168.123.252  192.168.123.252      20
  192.168.123.252  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
  192.168.123.255  255.255.255.255  192.168.123.252  192.168.123.252      20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0  192.168.123.252  192.168.123.252      20
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255  192.168.123.252               2       1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255  192.168.123.252  192.168.123.252      1
Default Gateway:   192.168.123.254
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipv6 nc

```
6: fe80::ffff:ffff:fffd 0.0.0.0:0         permanent
5: fe80::203:ffff:fee1:6c89 00-03-ff-e1-6c-89 permanent
4: fe80::203:ffff:fee6:6c89                   incomplete
2: fe80::5efe:192.168.123.252 127.0.0.1         permanent
1:            fe80::1                   permanent
1:                ::1                   permanent
```

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipv6 if

```
Interface 6: Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  Guid {DD5FD1F6-E257-47CB-9F44-57FF4738C478}
  zones: link 6 site 3
  cable unplugged
  uses Neighbor Discovery
  uses Router Discovery
  routing preference 2
  link-layer address: 0.0.0.0:0
    preferred link-local fe80::ffff:ffff:fffd, life infinite
    multicast interface-local ff01::1, 1 refs, not reportable
    multicast link-local ff02::1, 1 refs, not reportable
  link MTU 1280 (true link MTU 1280)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 18000ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 0
  default site prefix length 48
Interface 5: Ethernet: Local Area Connection 2
  Guid {E60C0BEF-BAE6-4E6A-929A-10DA739EB95F}
  uses Neighbor Discovery
  uses Router Discovery
  link-layer address: 00-03-ff-e1-6c-89
    preferred link-local fe80::203:ffff:fee1:6c89, life infinite
    multicast interface-local ff01::1, 1 refs, not reportable
    multicast link-local ff02::1, 1 refs, not reportable
    multicast link-local ff02::1:ffe1:6c89, 1 refs, last reporter
  link MTU 1500 (true link MTU 1500)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 17500ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 1
  default site prefix length 48
Interface 4: Ethernet: Local Area Connection
  Guid {FBF53FC5-3CEC-491A-AEF1-49918DBA552F}
  zones: link 4 site 2
  cable unplugged
  uses Neighbor Discovery
  uses Router Discovery
  link-layer address: 00-03-ff-e6-6c-89
    tentative link-local fe80::203:ffff:fee6:6c89, life infinite
    multicast interface-local ff01::1, 1 refs, not reportable
    multicast link-local ff02::1, 1 refs, not reportable
    multicast link-local ff02::1:ffe6:6c89, 1 refs, last reporter
  link MTU 1500 (true link MTU 1500)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 43500ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 1
  default site prefix length 48
Interface 3: 6to4 Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  Guid {A995346E-9F3E-2EDB-47D1-9CC7BA01CD73}
  does not use Neighbor Discovery
  does not use Router Discovery
  routing preference 1
  link MTU 1280 (true link MTU 65515)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 39000ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 0
  default site prefix length 48
Interface 2: Automatic Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  Guid {48FCE3FC-EC30-E50E-F1A7-71172AEEE3AE}
  does not use Neighbor Discovery
  does not use Router Discovery
  routing preference 1
  EUI-64 embedded IPv4 address: 0.0.0.0
  router link-layer address: 0.0.0.0
    preferred link-local fe80::5efe:192.168.123.252, life infinite
  link MTU 1280 (true link MTU 65515)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 33500ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 0
  default site prefix length 48
Interface 1: Loopback Pseudo-Interface
  Guid {6BD113CC-5EC2-7638-B953-0B889DA72014}
  zones: link 1 site 4
  does not use Neighbor Discovery
  does not use Router Discovery
  link-layer address:
    preferred link-local ::1, life infinite
    preferred link-local fe80::1, life infinite
  link MTU 1500 (true link MTU 4294967295)
  current hop limit 128
  reachable time 33500ms (base 30000ms)
  retransmission interval 1000ms
  DAD transmits 0
  default site prefix length 48
```

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipv6 -v rt

```
fe80::5efe:192.168.123.252/128 -> 2/fe80::5efe:192.168.123.252 pref 1if+4=5 life infinite (system)
fe80::ffff:ffff:fffd/128 -> 6/fe80::ffff:ffff:fffd pref 2if+4=6 life infinite (system)
ff00::/8 -> 5 pref 8 life infinite (system)
fe80::203:ffff:fee1:6c89/128 -> 5/fe80::203:ffff:fee1:6c89 pref 4 life infinite (system)
ff00::/8 -> 4 pref 8 life infinite (system)
fe80::203:ffff:fee6:6c89/128 -> 4/fe80::203:ffff:fee6:6c89 pref 4 life 0s (system)
::1/128 -> 1/::1 pref 4 life infinite (system)
ff00::/8 -> 1 pref 8 life infinite (system)
fe80::1/128 -> 1/fe80::1 pref 4 life infinite (system)
```

Ipv works perfectly everywhere, but with ipv6 i can only ping the host machine, there isn't even a default route. Has it been like this for others, that have to manually configure everything starting from routes?

At least, if you could provide me printouts for same commands on your system, to give me some ideas.

(What's interesting is that Interface 5: Ethernet: Local Area Connection 2, doesn't even feature in route printout despite it's the connected network, in reality an Intel Wifi Link 5300 on the host.)

Comment: Do you actually have IPv6 connectivity? Describe your IPv6 network.

Comment: Yes ipv6 works otherwise very well from all physical machines. Router with 6in tunnel, DHCPv6, mix of manually and autoconfigured ipv6 addresses. XPmode is using a static ipv6 address now. I can ping the host machine even without a default or other route to it. But attempts to configure a ::/0 default route to anywhere are not a success, packets are not moving out of the host.

Comment: Thinking if it could be some weird firewall issue with the host, but i cannot find the executables vpc.exe and VMWindow.exe anywhere except somewhere deep in winsxs directories. How to create fw rules for them then?!? Host has fw enabled both in and out.

Comment: Have you tried stateless autoconfiguration? [XP's IPv6 support was _very_ limited](http://serverfault.com/a/413398/126632), and SLAAC was often the only thing that worked reliably. Of particular note, XP does not do DHCPv6.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to turn it on, if it's not on by default. Updated the question with settings for a plain vanilla system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPV6 does work inside XP Mode. No problems loading http://ipv6.google.com or http://test-ipv6.com/ here.

VM Networking: bridged (regular network adapter selected, same one main machine uses for everything).

Inside XP Mode: installed "Microsoft TCP/IP version 6" for the Local Area Connection, Intel 21140-Based PCI fast Ethernet adapter.

Router: I use a public 6to4 tunnel (192.88.99.1) no IPV6 DNS configured because the IPv4 accessible name server I use returns IPv6 addresses (IPV6 DNS fields left blank in 6to4 settings).

Not sure where you are going wrong. Using a bridged adapter is similar to having a virtual Ethernet switch and the VM is connected like any other local machine to your LAN.

Double check there isn't some security setting on your wireless router than only gives wireless clients one IP address (you need one for your machine and one for each VM set to use a bridged network connection). Try a wired connection and bridge that to see if this might be the source of the problem.

---

First part of IPCONFIG /ALL and ping of the router and ipv6.google.com from the XP Mode VM.

```
C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualXP-41525
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : MyLocalNet

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MyLocalNet
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel 21140-Based PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (Generic
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-03-FF-55-46-4B
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:18f6:3f2:1:a848:b95e:2b24:7b83
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:18f6:3f2:1:203:ffff:fe55:464b
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::203:ffff:fe55:464b%4
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                            fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 206.248.154.22
                                            206.248.154.170
                                            fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                            fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                            fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, November 19, 2013 5:44:33 PM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, November 20, 2013 5:44:33 PM
```

---

```
C:\>ping6 fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4

Pinging fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4
from fe80::203:ffff:fe55:464b%4 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4: bytes=32 time<1ms
Reply from fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4: bytes=32 time<1ms
Reply from fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4: bytes=32 time<1ms
Reply from fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4: bytes=32 time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::218:e7ff:fef1:158e%4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\>ping6 ipv6.google.com

Pinging ipv6.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013]
from 2002:18f6:3f2:1:a848:b95e:2b24:7b83 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013: bytes=32 time=76ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013: bytes=32 time=100ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013: bytes=32 time=56ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013: bytes=32 time=35ms

Ping statistics for 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1013:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 35ms, Maximum = 100ms, Average = 66ms
```

---

Router IPv6 Configuration
[image]

Router IPv6 Status
[image]

Comment: XPmode has a static ipv6 address. It doesn't see anything in the network, only the host computer. Router has ipv6 router advertisements on but they're not seen by XPmode.

Comment: But it gets ipv dhcp address from router just fine.

Comment: Please, could you provide outputs for the commands listed on the updated question, to give me some pointers.